# Defining recursive data structures

Tags: math, haskell

I'm trying to learn Haskell, thinking that it would be the perfect language to implement [Combinatorial Game Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory). I've done this to some extent in Python to teach myself OOP principles and operator overloading, but Haskell attracts me because it seems more mathematical in its syntax, and having a math background I really like that. Also, having lazily implemented infinite lists is pretty amazing.

Anyway, what I have so far is a data structure that compiles but the first function I've written using it gives me:

```
Prelude> :l cgt
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( cgt.hs, interpreted )

cgt.hs:8:30:
    Couldn't match expected type `([Game], b0)' with actual type `Game'
    In the first argument of `fst', namely `b'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `(fst b)'
    In the expression: a : (fst b)
    Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Here is my code...

```
--A game that is Zero (base case) is two empties
--Anything else must be two lists of games, a left list and a right list.

data Game = Zero
          | Position ([Game], [Game])

putL :: Game -> Game -> Game
putL a b = Position (a :(fst b), snd b)
```

I realize that a Game is somewhat like a Tree as discussed on the [Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Other_data_structures#Trees) , but they have additional restrictions.

1. A Position (kin to a tree node) can have many possible moves
2. A Position may only contain other Games
3. There is a special Game, Zero, that has no possible moves.
4. All games are built up using Zero.

So when I wrote `putL` I say, "Take a Game `a` and another Game `b`, and cons `a` into the first part of `b`, and leave the second part of `b` alone, returning a Position (which is a kind of Game)." At least, that is what I am trying to do. Instead Haskell is thinking the type I'm returning is `([Game], b0)` and I don't know why.

Thank you! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use the `fst` and `snd` functions on something of type `Game`. Since you haven't declared names for your fields in your data constructors `Zero` and `Position`, the only way to actually access them is via pattern matching. (Note that I also removed the unnecessary tuple in the `Position` constructor)

```
data Game
  = Zero
  | Position [Game] [Game]

putL :: Game -> Game -> Game
putL game Zero = ???
putL game (Position games1 games2) = Position (game : games1) games2
```

Now, I obviously don't know what you want to happen for the `Zero` constructor, so you'll have to fill in those `???`'s yourself.

Comment: Actually, the zero game is already represented by `Position [] []` so there is no need for an extra constructor for it.

Comment: I see. I used a tuple because I only wanted to have two sets of positions, but that is unnecessary because the two lists are defined in the data structure.

And for the function, you can define what type goes in as a position, returning what I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

dflemstr's answer is correct. I am going to explain the error message you got.

- `a : fst b` must have type `[Game]` --- agreed, yes?
- therefore `a` must have type `Game`... (and it does, hooray)
- ...and `fst b` must have type `[Game]`
- [`fst`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:fst) takes a pair as input, and yields the first element of the pair, so...
- ...`b` must have type `([Game], b0)` (for some type `b0` that we haven't worked out yet) (this is the *expected* type)
- this is a problem because according to the type signature for `putL`, `b` must have type `Game` (this is the *actual* type) --- it can't be a pair